# Change XLM to TRON

Tags: transactions, token, wallets

Can you help me to cancel transfer of 3150 XLM throw bybit to GDV6B27VOD2YSFK7ZTFMY4YQQFIDT4KF4SD4IHF2PCSFYFZBREC6XTG4 sammokix .com

I tried to change 3150 to TRON on site but didn't watch attentively, there was 3151, so I made a mistake, and my offer wasn't succesful.They wrote that I must transfer such a sum of 3151 and then transfer txid a421c9ef05d157b154d9ee83be88c9dda03518e4f3de3abfd40bbfaee171712c will be cancelled. I don't have such money to do so.

[image]
[image]